# Axios, is it slower to auto catch error responses (such as 404)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Just a curiosity question, for the package axios in javascript, node or otherwise, the default setting is to throw an error for any response 400 or greater (not sure if that's exactly right but meh). I have previously been taught that using catch where a if statement could have worked fine is generally considered bad practice. To get to my question, in circumstances where 404 errors are expected fairly frequently, would it be better to use a if statement instead of a catch (for the package axios this means moving away from the default settings using validateStatus)?

Things to consider, does being on AWS lambda change anything? Is it different for different node versions or JavaScript versions/browsers?

Any insight appreciated :)

Comment: "Slower"? Quite possibly, but if so, probably by an utterly imperceptible amount in 99% of situations. Better not to worry about it and choose whichever way of formatting your code is most readable.

Comment: _"throw an error"_... not exactly. Axios returns a promise that either resolves (success) or rejects (failure). You can configure the failure status if required. Any opinions about when to use `if..else` vs `try..catch` are just that, opinions. Such questions are off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: @Phil This explains why its not slow, thanks. Follow up question, lets say it was using throw instead of promise reject, would in that case it cause significant performance drops (only for high volumes of calls of course)?

Comment: I'd say do your own profiling and make a decision based on the results. I have seen no evidence to say whether `throw` performs any differently to `return Promise.reject()` in async code

Answer (score -2):

`Axios` is not by any noticeable means slower than `fetch`. The tradeoffs between using Axios or handling your own raw `http` requests is not worth it for many developers.

Check out [Axios Interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors). It lets you deal with requests and responses *before* they're handled in the `then` or `catch` blocks.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  return req;
});

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => res,
  (err) => {
    if (err?.response?.status != null) {
      console.log(`Intercepted status: ${err.response.status}`);
    } else {
      console.log(
        `No response from server, using request status`,
        err.request.status
      );
    }
    return Promise.reject(err);
  }
);
```

Here's [an example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react18-express-axios-interceptor-handling-status-codes-ktnfxu) I put together recently showing interceptors in-action.

There's no concern with using Axios on AWS Lambda. The newer versions of Axios would not work with old Node.js versions but it's very dependent on the package version. Generally not something to worry about.